# How to clone json array without changing the value of existing json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like below

```
[{
    "shiftNo": "shift 1",
    "UserId": 4,
    "UserName": "Felicia Frazier",
    "opnAmt": 0,
    "ClsAmt": 0,
    "RegisterName": "kano",
    "RegisterId": 2,
    "ZId": 19,
        "OpenDate": "2014-11-24 08:51:56.000",
    "CloseDate": "2014-11-24 16:58:02.000",
    "Total": 21.83,
        "PaymentDetails": [{
        "PayId": 1,
        "PaymentName": "Cash",
        "PaidAmount": 0
    }, {
        "PayId": 2,
        "PaymentName": "Check",
        "PaidAmount": 0
    }, {
        "PayId": 3,
        "PaymentName": "Credit Card",
        "PaidAmount": 21.83
    }]
},

{
    "shiftNo": "shift 1",
    "UserId": 5,
    "UserName": "Dewayne Frazier",
    "opnAmt": 0,
    "ClsAmt": 0,
    "RegisterName": "kano",
    "RegisterId": 2,
    "ZId": 19,
        "OpenDate": "2014-11-24 08:51:56.000",
    "CloseDate": "2014-11-24 16:58:02.000",
    "Total": 26.2,
        "PaymentDetails": [{
        "PayId": 1,
        "PaymentName": "Cash",
        "PaidAmount": 5.45
    }, {
        "PayId": 2,
        "PaymentName": "Check",
        "PaidAmount": 0
    }, {
        "PayId": 3,
        "PaymentName": "Credit Card",
        "PaidAmount": 20.75
    }]
},


{
    "shiftNo": "shift 2",
    "UserId": 5,
    "UserName": "Dewayne Frazier",
    "opnAmt": 202.91,
    "ClsAmt": 0,
    "RegisterName": "kano",
    "RegisterId": 6,
    "ZId": 20,
        "OpenDate": "2014-11-24 10:32:23.000",
    "CloseDate": "2014-11-24 22:01:37.000",
    "Total": 2380.69,
        "PaymentDetails": [{
        "PayId": 1,
        "PaymentName": "Cash",
        "PaidAmount": 818.65
    }, {
        "PayId": 2,
        "PaymentName": "Check",
        "PaidAmount": 90.1
    }, {
        "PayId": 3,
        "PaymentName": "Credit Card",
        "PaidAmount": 1471.94
    }]
},

{
    "shiftNo": "shift 2",
    "UserId": 7,
    "UserName": "Kelvin Daniels",
    "opnAmt": 100,
    "ClsAmt": 0,
    "RegisterName": "kano",
    "RegisterId": 6,
    "ZId": 20,
        "OpenDate": "2014-11-24 10:32:23.000",
    "CloseDate": "2014-11-24 22:01:37.000",
    "Total": 1516.33,
        "PaymentDetails": [{
        "PayId": 1,
        "PaymentName": "Cash",
        "PaidAmount": 1516.33
    }, {
        "PayId": 2,
        "PaymentName": "Check",
        "PaidAmount": 0
    }, {
        "PayId": 3,
        "PaymentName": "Credit Card",
        "PaidAmount": 0
    }]
}]
```

now I am doing grouping for this array Shift Wise in below function

I have assign above JSON in

`var ParsedJson = above JSON.`

I am using below function for this:

```
var SubGridResult = getShiftReportSubGridGroupedValue(ParsedJson, groupColumnName, RegisterName);

function getShiftReportSubGridGroupedValue(sourceResult, groupColumnName, RegisterName) {

    //ParsedJson.filter(function (v) { return v[groupColumnName] == getRemovedCountFormatedValue(jQuery('#tblShiftSummaryReport').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, groupColumnName).trim()) }),
    var pGroupedResult = new Array();
    var GroupedResult1 = sourceResult.slice();
    var GroupedResult1234 = GroupedResult1.filter(function (v) { return v[groupColumnName] == RegisterName });

    $.each(GroupedResult1234, function (index, item) {
        var itemResult = new Array();
        itemResult = pGroupedResult.filter(function (value) { return value["shiftNo"] == item["shiftNo"] });
        if (itemResult.length > 0) {
            itemResult[0].ItemCount++;
            itemResult[0].opnAmt += parseFloat(item["opnAmt"]);
            itemResult[0].ClsAmt += parseFloat(item["ClsAmt"]);
            itemResult[0].Total += parseFloat(item["Total"]);
            var itemmm = itemResult[0].GroupedPaymentDetails;
            $.each(itemResult[0].GroupedPaymentDetails, function (indexIn, itemIn) {
                itemResult[0].GroupedPaymentDetails[indexIn]["PaidAmount"] += parseFloat(item["PaymentDetails"][indexIn]["PaidAmount"]);
            });
        } else {
            var newItemObj = new Object();
            newItemObj.ItemCount = 1;
            newItemObj.shiftNo = item["shiftNo"];
            newItemObj.RegisterName = item["RegisterName"];
            newItemObj.opnAmt = parseFloat(item["opnAmt"]);
            newItemObj.ClsAmt = parseFloat(item["ClsAmt"]);
            newItemObj.GroupedPaymentDetails = new Array();
            newItemObj.GroupedPaymentDetails = item["PaymentDetails"].slice();
            newItemObj.Total = parseFloat(item["Total"]);



            pGroupedResult.push(newItemObj);
        }
    });
    return pGroupedResult;
};
```

The first time it gives me a proper result but then also the new data is updated to my original JSON. how to prevent it from being updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**jQuery.extend()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var ParsedJson = jQuery.extend(true, {}, YOUR_JSON);
```

Comment: hi Samurai , i have already used it but facing same problem. the main problem is its updates the data  of PaymentDetails which is another array in every shift  you can see.

Comment: finally this works for me when i use your method in my PaymentDetails array like  newItemObj.GroupedPaymentDetails = jQuery.extend(true, {}, item["PaymentDetails"]); //item["PaymentDetails"];

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var secondJSON = Object.create( firstJSON ).
```

The second json is now independent from the first one.

[developer.mozilla.org/object/create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)